# Azure Data Studio - how to access Activity Monitor

Tags: ssms, azure-data-studio, activity-monitor

I've recently installed ADS but I can't find how to view the activity monitor.
In SSMS, you can easily access the activity monitor and view which queries are blocked, Active expensive queries, recent expensive queries etc.

Is this available in ADS?

#### SSSMS

[image: SSMS]

#### Azure Data Studio

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pass a lot of time, but if it still is useful...

There isn't support to Activity Monitor with Azure Data Studio.
For some tasks, you can use *exec sp_who2*.

Refer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/39118524-5806-4545-a1e3-8e73d0fcb73e/does-sql-azure-support-activity-monitor-feature?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure is a RDBMS-As-A-Service, No "Activity Monitor" available unlike native SSMS. However use azure portal for collecting metrics / creating alert dash board etc. Also you can use Azure Data studio with couple of "extensions" available for monitoring/creating reports/etc.